# how to convert an array of strings to array of numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have this part of project that I need to convert a `Number` to an `Array`, then I have to add `+1` to every digit
I wrote this code, still it return `undefined`

```
function Nbr1(a){
    return a.toString().split('').map(Number).forEach( (item, index) => item + 1);
}
console.log(Nbr1(12345))
```

and I got this result

[image]

and when I add `console.log` to every item in forEach, I got this

[image]

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach`

Comment: The [documentation of `.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) tells you that [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return anything: _"Return value: `undefined`."_

Comment: What about `9`? should it be replaced with `10` or `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `forEach` after `map`. `map` already iterates through the array.

And don't forget to convert the array item to a number with a `+` before it because you generated an array of strings

```js
function Nbr1(a) {
  return a.toString().split("").map((number) => +number + 1)
}

console.log(Nbr1(12345))
```

[Learn more about `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: _"...because you generated an array of strings"_ - No, OP did not. The conversion is done by `.map(Number)` (the capital `N` makes the difference ;))

Comment: `.split` returns an array of strings. [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: The script is `a.toString().split('').map(Number)` and `.map(Number)` does the conversion

Comment: That doesn't make the statement "because you generated an array of strings" wrong

Comment: _"And don't forget to convert the array item to a number with a + before it because **you generated an array of strings**"_ - Is wrong because OP converted them into numbers before the `+1`. You removed the conversion and added it again with the unary `+`.

Comment: I removed his conversion to add the arrow function that manipulates the number. With the `Number` callback there I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

See short example below with usage of `parseInt()`. No extra `forEach` required.

```js
function Nbr1(a){
    return a.toString().split('').map((number)=>{
        return parseInt(number) + 1
    })    
}
console.log(Nbr1(12345))
```